# Powershell Throwing an Error - out of memory (I think)

Tags: powershell, error-handling

PowerShell is throwing this error...

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:23 char:14
+              $diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item($col1,2) = [String]$Flowerbox
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Line 23 is this bit of code..

```
$diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item($col1,2) = [String]$Flowerbox
```

I have 10K+ files.  In those files are descriptions of what the files do.  The descriptions are in a flowerbox (A bunch of notes surrounded by asterisk).
The common theme to them, is that all comments begin after "IDENTIFICATION DIVISION" and end before "ENVIRONMENT DIVISION"

So I load up an array with everything I find from the "*" and out 62 positions.
After, I write the Excel information, I reset my array.

Out of the 10K+ Files, I get a few hundred of the exceptions above and it fails to capture the needed data.

I added some error handling and generated the expanded messages below.

```
PSItem.InvocationInfo..... System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
PSItem.Exception.......... System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
   at System.Management.Automation.ComInterop.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, ComMethodDesc method, Object[] args, UInt32 argErr)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , Object , Int32 , String )
   at <ScriptBlock>(Closure , FunctionContext )
PSItem.Exception.Message.. Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

Any Idea why I'm heading south?
Here is my script....

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $False
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$diskSpacewksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$diskSpacewksht.Name = "Descriptions"
$col1=1
$diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item(1,1) = 'Program'
$diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item(1,2) = 'Description'

$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\HOLD_Files' -Filter '*.cbl' -File -Recurse
$Flowerbox = @()

ForEach($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
    $Flowerbox = @()
    Write-Host "Processing ... $CBLFile" -foregroundcolor green      
    Get-content -Path $CBLFile.FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match 'IDENTIFICATION DIVISION') {
            $treat = $true
        }
        if ($_ -match 'ENVIRONMENT DIVISION') {
             $col1++
             $diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item($col1,1) = $CBLFile
             $diskSpacewksht.Cells.Item($col1,2) = [String]$Flowerbox
             $Flowerbox = @()
             continue
        }
        if ($treat) {
            if ($_ -match '\*(.{62})') {
                Foreach-Object {$Flowerbox += $matches[1] + "`r`n"}
            }
        }
    }
}

$excel.DisplayAlerts = 'False'
$ext=".xlsx"
$path="C:\OUTPUT_RESULTS\Captured_Results_2$ext"
$workbook.SaveAs($path) 
$workbook.Close
$excel.DisplayAlerts = 'False'
$excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you reset the $Flowerbox variable after each $CBLFile.

Comment: Hi @Dan I added the reset (See code above).  I still throw the error.

Comment: The only other recommendation is to put in more debug output to see what is going on with $Flowerbox within the 'ENVIRONMENT DIVISION' conditional statement. Add breakpoints to see what is actually going on as well. I suspect that a file that you have is giving you problems and may or may not have the end of line delimiters, possibly causing memory issues.

Comment: I checked the files that were throwing the error.  From my observation, things look ok - I am going to add another check to verify one or the other.  Your prolly right...